# Cannot GET /api/courses/1 errror how to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, nodemon

```
const express = require('express');


const app = express();

app.get('/',(req,res) =>{       // result shows on localhost:3000
    res.send('hello world');
});

app.get('/api/courses',(req,res) =>{    // result shows on localhost:3000/api/courses
    res.send(\[1,2,3\]);
});

app.get('/api/courses/:id',(req,res) =>{    // result does not show on localhost:3000/api/courses/1
    res.send(req.param.id);
});

//PORT


const port= process.env.PORT||3000;


app.listen(port,()=\>console.log(\``Listening to port ${port}...`\`));
```

I seem to be getting result for the first 2 get functions but not the ID, i get the following error Cannot GET /api/courses/1 how do i fix it ?

was expecting output of id as '1' to display

Comment: res.send(req.param.id); should be req.params.id

Answer (score 1):

You did have a syntax error in your `console.log()` line when starting the server: ``` console.log(``Listening to port ${port}...\) ``` is not valid JavaScript (this might have been just an editing error when you pasted your code here).

But most important, you are missing an `s` in `param`. It should be `req.params.id`.

Below code does work for me. I've tested it using Postman.

```js
import express from "express";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // result shows on localhost:3000

  res.send("hello world");
});

app.get("/api/courses", (req, res) => {
  // result shows on localhost:3000/api/courses

  res.send([1, 2, 3]);
});

app.get("/api/courses/:id", (req, res) => {
  // // result does not show on localhost:3000/api/courses/1 res.send(req.param.id);
  res.send(`This handler has received the value ${req.params.id} for ID`);
});

//PORT

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: previously i had used res.send(req.params.id) and it dint work,however when i applied the format you gave it worked which is this   res.send(`This handler has received the value ${req.params.id} for ID`),using template string /  Thanks a lot for the solution .

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking this as an [*accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) if this worked for you :)